# Is there an app that can measure STC of a building? Sound transmission class

Tags: building-regulations

I am DIY renovating a historic building, putting apartments on the 2nd floor and office space on the 1st floor.

I know from the building code I need to meet a sound transmission class of `STC 50`.

Looking at the all of the UL-rated assemblies, there is no existing assembly I can point to in a book that corresponds to what I have (diagram below).

Is there an app or something I could use on my phone, that would measure the volume levels downstairs and calculate the STC I have currently?

(Yes, I am also just going to ask the building inspector what he wants me to do here...)

[image]

Comment: There's apps that measure DBs, then you can plug those into existing formulas. You crank a stereo on one floor, and measure right next to it, then go to the other floor and measure again to get an idea of the roll-off.

Comment: STC’s are additive. You could add up each component.